# Structr vs spring-data-neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, structr

I have a modest amount of experience using [spring-data-neo4j](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j) to facilitate object-to-graph mapping and provide infrastructures for Java-based web-applications built on neo4j. By and large I've been happy with SDN - it can certainly do a lot, but I have encountered some use-cases where it feels like too much - where most of what it can do is not required, and where it adds unnecessary complexity to providing the relatively simple functionalities that are required.

I've just come across [structr](http://structr.org/home) [(github)](https://github.com/structr/structr) and am intrigued by it, specifically when it comes to these sorts of use-cases. The [documentation](http://docs.structr.org/) is pretty good, but I'm finding very few discussions about it in the community. *(there wasn't even an SO tag until now!)* So I'm posting this question to ask:

Have you ever used structr? If so:

- What did you do with it? How did it go?
- What would you consider an ideal use case for it? Where might it not be the best tool?
- Are there any big pitfalls or gotchas you would point out to someone who is just beginning to think about using it?

Comment: I haven't used it but want to thank you for pointing me to it. There are some people where I work who will be very interested in this.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm the founder of Structr) Maybe the wording of the question is difficult. Structr is an application with CMS character, targeting end-users, while SDN is a developer framework.